# MyProgram has stopped working error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mvvm, exe

I have created a C#/MVVM project which runs fine when I run it from within VS2010.  I copied the exe file from the /release folder to the desktop and tried to run it as a standalone program and get the error message "MyProgram has stopped working"

My solution has two projects to it, MyProgram and MyProgramModel (...Model contains the EDMX model of the database items).  The MyProgram project is set as the start up project.

Is there something I am missing when creating an exe for C#/MVVM?

Comment: Your executable probably depends on some other things in the /Release folder that you didn't copy out. Also, what's a C#/MVVM project? Are you referring to the MVVM Light framework by any chance?

Comment: C#/MVVM just means I wrote a C# program using the MVVM methodology/framework in case that had anything to do with the exe file output.

Comment: I do have other libraries that are used by the project in the /Release directory.  Is there a way to make a single exe file that I can run or do I have to copy all the files from the /Release directory to my Desktop in order to run outside of VS2010?

Comment: Assuming you're running on Windows, you might find more information about this exception in Window's Event Viewer ("Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\Event Viewer").

Comment: @BrianKE: to merge multiple assemblies into one exe take a look at ilmerge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BoltClock stated there should be another file in the Release folder you should copy also. Probably this is a dll named MyProgramModel.dll or something similar.
In order to receive more information you can wait Windows to try to do something to repair your program and then you will probably be displayed with a dialog similar to [this one](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_JbBl6k5xSgs/S9prbakUczI/AAAAAAAABTk/VYpiCE77dR0/s1600/catalyst+install+manager+has+stopped+working.jpg). Click on debug and there should be a more comprehensive error you can consider.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that all binaries included in your Project References are in the same directory as your application. The only time where this is not necessary is if you have used some kind of third-party .NET linker application, or have installed your project's dependencies in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

In short, just ensure all *.dll and *.exe assemblies referenced by your project are in the same directory when you execute the application. Visual Studio does this for you by default during testing, by placing them in the Release / Debug folder(s). You do not need to include the *.vshost.exe application, as this is a simple stub application used for debugging purposes.

If you insist on deploying as a single application, you'll need to consider a third-party linker:

- http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/
- http://cleansofts.org/net-linker.html

Other solutions include a Setup Deployment Package which can be created in Visual Studio, or Click-Once deployment. Both are forms of traditional installation technologies:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353

Comment: Marked Dimitar's answer as the accepted since it did answer the direct question but also like this one as I would like to deploy my app as a single file (or at least as a single installation file).